# Crontab in Docker with flask application

Tags: mysql, docker, flask, docker-compose, cron

I'm trying to create cronjob within the docker container, But the it doesn't work. Below is my code

Dockerfile

```
 FROM python:3
 LABEL image for a very management application
 # We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
 COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
 WORKDIR /app
 RUN apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
 RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
 RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
 COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/cjob
 RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cjob
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 CMD cron -f
 EXPOSE 5000
 COPY . .
 CMD ["cron", "-f"]
 CMD [ "python3", "app.py" ]
```

crontab

```
 */5 * * * * root /test.py >> /logfile
```

test.py

```
from datetime import datetime
print("Our test works at", datetime.now())
```

I'm tring to run cronjob with the

```
docker-compose up
```

Is anything wrong i'm doing, Is their any other way for cronjob to work. Please can anyone help me. Thank you all

Comment: [There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Comment: @Victor thank you for the hint. Do have any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can mainly run one CMD you will need to use the ENTRYPOINT directive. I can give you an example of how I made it work.

The theory behind the solution is that in the base image during build time you prepare all the necessary documents:

- copy in the crontab file and apply it
- Copy in the additional launch script
- set ENTRYPOINT to the launch script
- run CMD and start your app

Example:

```
COPY token-renewal-cron /etc/cron.d/token-renewal-cron
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/token-renewal-cron
```

where crontab logic is inside token-renewal-cron

Then you need to copy the launch script into the /usr/local/bin/ directory

```
COPY launch.sh /usr/local/bin/launch.sh
RUN chmod 0777 /usr/local/bin/launch.sh #0777 as long as it works for POC :)
```

Where in our case launch.sh contains:

```
cron # this starts the cron process
TMP # some commands we need to run next to cron command (we prepare app env here)

# Append CMD from Dockerfile NOTE this is important so you can then use CMD after ENTRYPOINT inside DOCKERFILE
exec "$@"
```

Then at the end of the DOCKERFILE you just prepare ENTRYPOINT and CMD commands

```
#Launch our entrypoint script
ENTRYPOINT ["launch.sh"]
#Launch our application
CMD ["dotnet", "APPLICATION.dll"]
```

Comment: i tried the as you mentioned above but i get the error as  "exited with code 1" i added the above line as you mentioned  ´
ENTRYPOINT ["launch.sh"]
CMD [ "python3", "app.py" ]´ is their any wrong in my cmd? In launch.sh i created as same.

Comment: Could you put content of launch.sh?, so I can see what do you have in there?

It should only be

    cron and 
    exec "$@"

Comment: ´#!/bin/sh
cron 
exec "$@"´

Comment: above is my launch.sh, is , Is their any mistake in Dockerfile?

Comment: You should be left with this on your Dockerfile (format it):

 FROM python:3
 LABEL image for a very management application
 # We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
 COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
 WORKDIR /app
 RUN apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
 RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
 RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
 COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/cjob
 RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cjob
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 EXPOSE 5000
 COPY . .
 ENTRYPOINT ["launch.sh"]
 CMD [ "python3", "app.py" ]

Comment: In case you are receiving error 1, you should also check any logs you get why it would be failing maybe you need to use cron -f (or any additional parameters for your use case)